# Symfony 4 - Multiple pagination render with KnpPaginatorBundle?

Tags: symfony, view, pagination

I am trying to render several paginations on the same view.

In my template, I use tabs to separate my different lists, but I would like them each to have their pagination

For the moment I've :

**Controller.php**

```
public function index(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
{

    $productsLines = $stripeAdmin->findAllProducts();
    $products = $paginator->paginate(
        $productsLines,
        $request->query->getInt("page", 1),
        1
    );
    $products->setTemplate("pagination/stripePagination.html.twig");



    $couponsLines = $stripeAdmin->findAllCoupons();
    $coupons = $paginator->paginate(
        $couponsLines,
        $request->query->getInt("page", 1),
        1
    );
    $coupons->setTemplate("pagination/stripePagination.html.twig");

    return $this->render('stripe_admin/index.html.twig', [
        "products" => $products,
        "coupons" => $coupons,
    ]);
}
```

**template.html.twig:**

In each tab, I have this:

**Products tab:**

```
<div class="navigation">
    {{knp_pagination_render(products)}}
</div>
```

**Coupons tabs:**

```
<div class="navigation">
    {{knp_pagination_render(coupons)}}
</div>
```

But in the end I only have one that is rendered.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: it looks like you're having the same variable name in your query string for pagination. `$request->query->getInt("page", 1)` is used for both products and coupons. Use differents names

Comment: @Cid Should not impact knppaginator. But looks like issue is on the view parts.. Have you inspect your browser?

Comment: Yes I have inspected the browser and I confirm that the pagination element is only rendered once

Comment: edit : Ok it works if I use different name for the page ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to use the same template but with different query parameters in the same page I found this solution and I tested it successfully.

```
/** pagination 1 */
$pagination1 = $paginator->paginate(
    $queryContent1, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt("page1", 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/,
    array(
        'pageParameterName' => 'page1',
        'sortFieldParameterName' => 'sort1',
        'sortDirectionParameterName' => 'direction1',
    )
);

/** pagination 2 */
$pagination2 = $paginator->paginate(
    $queryContent2, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt("page2", 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/,
    array(
        'pageParameterName' => 'page2',
        'sortFieldParameterName' => 'sort2',
        'sortDirectionParameterName' => 'direction2',
    )
);

return $this->render('folder/view.html.twig', array(
    'list1' => $pagination1,
    'list2' => $pagination2
));
```

In the view:

```
{# first #}
{{ knp_pagination_render(list1) }}

{# second #}
{{ knp_pagination_render(list2) }}
```